# Vuex ORM Many-to-Many Relationship with pivot table with additional attributes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

i have a table: User, Role and the table has a many-to-many relationship with table pivots with additional attributes (approved, priority)

- **User**(id, name)
- **Role**(id, name)
- **RoleUser**(user_id, role_id, approved, priority).

How do I enter data, update data, retrieve data, and deleting data inside pivot tables (RoleUser) using vuex-orm?

my code looks like this:

```
class User extends Model {
    static entity = 'users'

    static fields() {
        return {
            id: this.attr(null),
            name: this.attr(''),
            roles: this.belongsToMany(Role, RoleUser, 'user_id', 'role_id')
        }
    }
}

class Role extends Model {
    static entity = 'roles'

    static fields() {
        return {
            id: this.attr(null),
            name: this.attr(''),
            users: this.belongsToMany(User, RoleUser, 'role_id', 'user_id')
        }
    }
}

class RoleUser extends Model {
    static entity = 'roleUser'

    static primaryKey = ['role_id', 'user_id']

    static fields() {
        return {
            role_id: this.attr(null),
            user_id: this.attr(null),
            approved: this.attr(''),
            priority: this.attr(''),
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

currently not yet implemented (*when this answer is made*).

current version: vuex-orm 0.31.7

**open issue**: [[FEATURE REQUEST] - Access to fields in pivot model](https://github.com/vuex-orm/vuex-orm/issues/321)

thanks you for [Kia King Ishii](https://github.com/kiaking) for the time and response given (via slack)

Answer (score 0):

It has been implemented since [v0.36.0](https://github.com/vuex-orm/vuex-orm/releases/tag/v0.36.0)

Here is the doc:  [Relationships / Many To Many](https://vuex-orm.org/guide/model/relationships.html#many-to-many)

PS: The 2022-03-08 they are still not documented in [Vuex Orm Next](https://next.vuex-orm.org/guide/relationships/getting-started.html#defining-relationships)

### Edit

After using Vuex Orm for 6 months, I strongly recommend not to use it as it is very buggy and doesn't seem to be maintained anymore

Some better solutions exist based on IndexDB like WatermelonDB, Dexie.js, RxDB or Gunjs

Comment: Just know that there is a critical bug that makes this feature unusable, the pivot data is the same for the entities with the same id (so if you had multiple times a `RoleUser` pivot and query from `User`, all of the `Roles` you will get multiple times the same role in the array and they will all have the same `pivot`)